# создать экземпляр класса с помощью переменной и пространства имен

Tags: php, ооп, namespace

Доброго времени суток.

Допустим есть переменная `$className = "Test"`.
Нужно создать экземпляр класса используя пространство имен.

```
$classObject = new liw\controllers\$className;
```

Выдаст ошибку:

> syntax error, unexpected '$className' (T_VARIABLE)

Как избавится от проблемы?

если сделать так, то все сработает, но правильно ли это?

```
$className = "Test";
$className = "liw\\controllers\\{$className}";
$classObject = new $className();
```

Comment: Наведите порядок в переменных/ошибках в вашем вопросе

Comment: "Правильно ли это?" Вполне

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, всё правильно. Строка с именем класса должна содержать полный namespace.

[Цитата](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)

> Если с директивой new используется строка (string), содержащая имя
>   класса, то будет создан новый экземпляр этого класса. Если имя
>   находится в пространстве имен, то оно должно быть задано полностью.

```
namespace app\test {
    class A{}
}
namespace {
    $a = new app\test\A;

    $name = 'A';
    $fullName = "app\\test\\{$name}";
    $a = new $fullName();
}
```

[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/0sQmS)